# A similar Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with linear-algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

Let $A$ be matrix in $M_{n}$ (i.e., $n\times n$ complex matrices), and $\|A\|\le 1$, we call it a contraction.

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are contractions such that
$I-AA^*$ and $I-BB^*$ are  positive-definite.

How to show that
$$\text{Tr}\left(1-AA^*\right)^{-1}\cdot \text{Tr}\left(1-BB^*\right)^{-1} \ge \left(\text{Tr}(1-AB^*)^{-1}\right)^2.$$

---

This problem is similar to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. (if you don't know the contraction matrix) and I found this paper give the contraction.  http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379507003710/1-s2.0-S0024379507003710-main.pdf?_tid=b1696360-f73a-11e3-9613-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1403131900_0ced864818647681ff916fc376a0f461

Comment: Are you saying that the article in the link proves this? If yes, what is your question?

Comment: The right hand side may be complex. I guess you may replace the bit brackets with | |.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to prove this.

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are contractions, first recall *Hua's Matrix Identity*
\begin{equation*}
  (I-B^*B) + (A-B)^*(I-AA^*)^{-1}(A-B) = (I-B^*A)(I-A^*A)^{-1}(I-A^*B).
\end{equation*}
From this it identity immediately follows that the following matrix is (Hermitian) positive definite:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
   (I-A^*A)^{-1} & (I-B^*A)^{-1}\\
   (I-A^*B)^{-1} & (I-B^*B)^{-1}
 \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{equation*}
From the operator inequality, taking trace (which preserves the positive semidefiniteness), we obtain the inequality in the OP.

Comment: The trace operator is to be applied "block-wise"...