# A stronger Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for traces of compression matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are contractions, so
$I-AA^T$ and $I-BB^T$ are  positive-definite matrices. Let
$C=(I-AB^T)^{-1}(I-AA^{T})(I-BA^{T})^{-1}$, and show that:

> $$Tr\left(\frac{1}{1-AA^T}\right)Tr\left(\frac{1}{1-BB^T}\right)-\left(Tr\left(\frac{1}{1-AB^T}\right)\right)^2
> $$
>
> $$ \ge Tr\left(\frac{1}{1-AA^T}\right)Tr\left([(A-B)^TC^2(A-B)]\right)\tag{1} $$

This is an attempt to strengthen this  inequality: [A similar Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with linear-algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172171/a-similar-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-with-linear-algebra).

I have two questions:

(1) How can one prove this inequality?

(2) Does equality hold if and only if $A=B$?

Comment: Is there any motivation for this inequality?

Comment: For the scalar case, this reduces (as expected) to AM-GM; but after that, this is a *Hua-type* trace inequality, and seems not to easy to prove.....